# Is it possible to merge two polygons with a single touching point into one?

Tags: polygon, convert

Is my understanding correct, namely that two polygons touching at a common point cannot be merged because the result would be a self-intersecting polygon? 
I know there are dozens of Q&A threads on self-intersecting polygons and I’ve looked through them.
This post: [Detecting invalid polygons (self-intersecting or touching)](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/69063/detecting-invalid-polygons-self-intersecting-or-touching?r=SearchResults&s=18|61.6432) seems to indicate merging 2 polygons with a single common point into one would create a self-intersecting polygon, and would thus be invalid. 
Likewise, the answer to this post [Is it possible to have self intersecting polygons in shapefile?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/37225/is-it-possible-to-have-self-intersecting-polygons-in-shapefile/43668?r=SearchResults&s=43|33.1590#43668) suggests such a geometry could not be stored in a shapefile.
However, this post seems to indicate it is possible to accomplish it: [Combining corner-touching polygons into a single feature](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/21744/combining-corner-touching-polygons-into-a-single-feature).

The reason I ask is that this post: [Merging polygons that share one vertex (node neighbors) using ArcGIS Desktop?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/322233/merging-polygons-that-share-one-vertex-node-neighbors-using-arcgis-desktop) suggests the user is trying to do exactly that and encountering errors. 
I’m posting it as a separate question here because my comment on that last post (poorly framed as a subsidiary question) was deemed invalid. Apologies in advance if I have not done the linking correctly in this question or I’ve deviated from protocol by referring to a deleted comment. I’m trying to improve my understanding of valid and invalid geometry.

Comment: The only database that will refuse to store an 'hourglass polygon' (A.K.A. Bowtie polygon) is enterprise; shapefiles, file and personal geodatabase etc. will happily store invalid geometries: Self intersecting, self overlapping, incorrect ring orientation etc are considered *non simple* geometries. As you might imagine the first step when receiving data from an untrustworthy source is to validate the geometries as these *non simple* geometries cause havoc with overlay operators (clip, erase, select by location etc). What software are you working with?

Comment: It's not invalid for a multipart polygon to have parts that  touch at a point.  Single part polygons can even have a hollow inclusion (which ArcGIS will accept; QGIS requires multipart).

Comment: I'm using QGIS and Global Mapper but my question is about shapefiles rather than software. If I understand what you are both saying, a "bow-tie" polygon is perfectly OK but would be considered a "non-simple geometry". It is not coming from an untrustworthy source but being created by a merge of two polygons with a common point. If I have this right then I'm answered and will close this.